# Subsheaf of tensor product of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tensor-products, sheaf-theory

I am reading the proof of Theorem II.7.6 in Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry", which states:

> Let $X$ be a scheme of finite type over a noetherian ring $A$, and $\mathscr{L}$ be an invertible sheaf on $X$. Then $\mathscr{L}$ is ample if and only if $\mathscr{L}^m$ is very ample over $\text{Spec} \; A$ for some $m > 0$.

In the proof of the direction $(\Rightarrow)$, they let $Y$ be a certain closed subscheme of $X$ and $\mathscr{I}_Y$ be its ideal sheaf, which is a coherent sheaf. Then by the ampleness of $\mathscr{L}$, we conclude that $\mathscr{I}_Y \otimes \mathscr{L}^n$ is globally generated, for some $n > 0$. Then the proof states:

> Now $\mathscr{I}_Y \otimes \mathscr{L}^n$ is a subsheaf of $\mathscr{L}^n$, so we can think of $s$ as an element of $\Gamma(X,\mathscr{L}^n)$

where $s \in \Gamma(X,\mathscr{I}_Y \otimes \mathscr{L}^n)$.

I don't understand how this statement is true. If you had a tensor product of sheaves $\mathscr{F} \otimes \mathscr{G}$, is there some way to see it as a subsheaf of its factors $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$? Or we are in some special situation involving $\mathscr{I}_Y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, this is something unique going on here - this remark relies on a couple special features of our situation.

$\mathcal{I}_Y$ injects in to $\mathcal{O}_X$ and $\mathcal{L}$ is flat (being a line bundle), so we get an injection $\mathcal{I}_Y\otimes\mathcal{L}^n\to\mathcal{O}_X\otimes\mathcal{L}^n$. As $\mathcal{O}_X\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{L}^n\cong\mathcal{L}^n$, we actually have an injection $\mathcal{I}_Y\otimes\mathcal{L}^n\to\mathcal{L}^n$, and taking global sections we get an injection $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{I}_Y\otimes\mathcal{L}^n)\to\Gamma(X,\mathcal{L}^n)$. That's how we're thinking of $s$ as an element of $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{L}^n)$.

Comment: Thank you. Also, another quick question: In the very next sentence, Hartshorne writes: "If $X_s$ is the open set $\{Q \in X \; | \; s_Q \notin \mathfrak{m}_Q\mathscr{L}_Q^n\}$, then it follows from our choice of $s$ that $P \in X_s$ and $X_s \subseteq U$." Do you know why $X_s \subseteq U$?

Comment: Could you remind me what $U$ is? I don't have the book in front of me.

Comment: Hartshorne writes: "For the converse, suppose that $\mathscr{L}$ is ample on $X$. Given any $P \in X$, let $U$ be an open affine neighbourhood of $P$ such that $\mathscr{L}\vert_U$ is free on $U$. Let $Y$ be the closed set $X - U$, and let $\mathscr{I}_Y$ be its sheaf of ideals... In particular, there is a section $s \in \Gamma(X,\mathscr{I}_Y\otimes\mathscr{L}^n)$ such that $s_P \notin \mathfrak{m}_P(\mathscr{I}_Y\otimes\mathscr{L}^n)_P$."

Comment: Sure, $s$ vanishes on $Y$ by construction so the nonvanishing set of $s$ is contained in the complement of $Y$, aka $U$.